# Pandas closest future value not equal to current row

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a Pandas DataFrame with one column, `price`, and a DateTimeIndex. I would like to create a new column that is 1 when `price` increases *the next time it changes* and 0 if it decreases. Multiple consecutive rows may have the same value of `price`.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"price" : [10, 10, 20, 10, 30, 5]}, index=pd.date_range(start="2017-01-01", end="2017-01-06"))
```

The output should then be:

```
2017-01-01     1
2017-01-02     1
2017-01-03     0
2017-01-04     1
2017-01-05     0
2017-01-06     NaN
```

In practice this DF has ~20mm rows so I'm really looking for a vectorized method of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

1. calculate the price difference and shift up by one;
2. use `numpy.where` to assign one to positions where price increases, zero to positions where price decreases;
3. back fill the indicator column, so non change values are the same as the next available observation;

In code:

```
import numpy as np
price_diff = df.price.diff().shift(-1)
df['indicator'] = np.where(price_diff.gt(0), 1, np.where(price_diff.lt(0), 0, np.nan))
df['indicator'] = df.indicator.bfill()

df
#            price  indicator
#2017-01-01     10      1.0
#2017-01-02     10      1.0
#2017-01-03     20      0.0
#2017-01-04     10      1.0
#2017-01-05     30      0.0
#2017-01-06      5      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['New']=(df-df.shift(-1))[:-1].le(0).astype(int)
df
Out[879]: 
            price  New
2017-01-01     10  1.0
2017-01-02     10  1.0
2017-01-03     20  0.0
2017-01-04     10  1.0
2017-01-05     30  0.0
2017-01-06      5  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

use shift:

```
sh = df['price'].shift(-1)
out = sh[~sh.isnull()] = df['price']<=sh
```

or

```
sh = df['price'].shift(-1)
out = np.where(sh.isnull(), np.nan, df['price']<=sh)
```